Exposing multiple AFP (Netatalk) services with Avahi/Zeroconf
I have followed the instruction to set up Time Capsule-compatible backup on a new NFS machine (it's written circa 2018 and is still perfectly working), and realised Netatalk might have advantages over Samba/CIFS shares.
I've created the second share in afp.conf and would like to expose it over Avahi along with Backups folder.
Avahi reads services from /etc/avahi/services folder in XML format, and a commonly used config for Time Capsule backup includes three parts (with _afpovertcp._tcp port, _device-info and _adisk._tcp sections). The latter looks like
  <service>
   <type>_adisk._tcp</type>
   <port>9</port>
   <txt-record>sys=waMa=0,adVF=0x100,adVU=fc2ecd9b-7c98-46bc-a53c-512e73a3cb82</txt-record>
   <txt-record>dk0=adVN=Backups,adVF=0x81</txt-record>
  </service>

How should I add the second disk exposed?

Well, from the first point of view it works by just adding a new block.
  <service>
   <type>_adisk._tcp</type>
   <port>9</port>
   <txt-record>sys=waMa=0,adVF=0x100,adVU=00000000-7c98-46bc-a53c-00000000cb82</txt-record>
   <txt-record>dk0=adVN=Backups,adVF=0x81</txt-record>
  </service>
  <service>
   <type>_adisk._tcp</type>
   <port>9</port>
   <txt-record>sys=waMa=0,adVF=0x100,adVU=00000000-7c98-46bc-a53c-00000000cb83</txt-record>
   <txt-record>dk0=adVN=Magic,adVF=0x81</txt-record>
  </service>

Or it's enough to expose the machine via Avahi in general, and the list of drives (not the special one exposed for Time Machine) will appear automatically in Finder. Can't tell precisely tho. the server is available and only the new folder is shown in Finder
